# AWS t2 burst mode ECU equivalence

Tags: amazon-ec2

Most EC2 instance types (except t2 ones) have a ECU value which indicates how powerful their CPU is. I would like to have the ECU value of the t2 instances at their maximum burst, but I cannot find this information anywhere. This is IMO pretty important to be able to compare t2 instances with m4 ones. Any idea if this value is available somewhere, or maybe someone has run test/benchmarks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ECU rating has been generally phased out because it does not necessarily represent a perfect comparison between instance types. Performance testing of your application on various different instance types is always the most accurate test.

The T2 family is very powerful while bursting. In the [CMP304: T2: From Startups to Enterprise, Performance for a Low Cost](https://youtu.be/FkMslBsVYFU) presentation at AWS re:Invent 2016, this slide shows the relative power of T2 instances:

[image: T2 performance comparison]

For a list of all AWS re:Invent 2016 presentations, see: [All AWS re:Invent 2016 presentations (including podcast versions)](http://aws-reinvent-audio.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2016/2016.html)